# Google Wallet - where's the merchant admin site

Tags: android-pay

Looking into Google Wallet for Digital Goods.

Signed up for a sandbox account.

Using Google's sample online demo, I can make purchases.

But where's the place where merchants can view all the orders.

I found a link at sandbox.google.com/checkout - but it doesn't
include the orders there.

Specifically I was wondering how with W4DG - one goes about
making refunds etc.

Thanks.

Comment: note: google checkout will no longer exist after nov 2013, set up with shopify http://www.shopify.com/googlecheckout or braintree https://www.braintreepayments.com/google-checkout?partner_source=google-checkout&utm_medium=ptn&utm_source=google-checkout&utm_campaign=google-checkout

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes, but that has _nothing_ to do with **Google Wallet For Digital Goods**. Only Google Checkout is being retired.

Comment: @EdSF just realised that after reading the link again - my bad

Comment: @RachelGallen Cool no apologies necessary and yes, there are 3rd party solutions too.

Comment: here's the link to the faq - i don't see anything about refunds http://www.google.ie/wallet/faq.html#tab=faq-instant

Comment: Yes I have a sandbox Checkout account and am trying to transition to Wallet for Digital Goods. I can make sandbox purchases - but they don't show up in the merchant console. The one I have is for Checkout. So how are W4DG merchants supposed to check for orders...make refunds etc. Maybe I can't use the same sandbox account as the one i used for Checkout.

Comment: I have a similar question.

I am trying to use wallet for digital goods (sandbox) but I cant get the seller and secret identifier. The link for that redirects me to google checkout which will soon stop functioning. \

so my qyestion is how can i use google wallet as a seller?

Comment: Question is not programming related. It's a support question for Google Wallet, and should be asked at their site.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wallet for digital good API documentation, see the "Managing orders" section:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/orders